# Mikro-orm different package versions compatability

Tags: npm, orm, mikro-orm

How does different mikro-orm packages versions correspond to each other? Could I possibly use @mikro-orm/core 4.0.0 and @mikro-orm/nestjs 3.1.0 or other variations of different @mikro-orm packages and their versions? Should all @mikro-orm packages be installed with same version?

It's 3 questions but I feel they are pretty much the same since they try to clarify concept of version matching in mikro-orm for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All packages that come from the main repository are released together, you should always align their versions.

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/tree/master/packages

The rest is not dependent on exact version, but in general, use the most up to date one. There are currently 3 packages that live outside of the main repo, the nest adapter you mentioned and 2 highlighters.

Btw there is no such release as `@mikro-orm/nestjs 3.1.0`, first release was `4.0.0` and current is `4.2.0`.

edit: apparently lerna is aligning only minor/feature releases, so it can happen that some packages are not on the very latest patch version, example of that are `mongo` and `reflection` packages, that are still on `4.1.0`, while the rest is on `4.1.1`. but again, use the latest everywhere and you will be fine. Your IDE should guide you in knowing the latest versions.

Comment: Yes, sorry about `@mikro-orm/nestjs` `3.1.0` it was just random version by me. 

This link is helpful. I can always see the alignment for certain release like this: https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/tree/22c92c750550bb2bfc94999c3ae82a9fb69dd09d/packages. 

My main concern was because of this `4.1.0` and `4.1.1` versions not aligning, now it is solved. Thank you.